# Python, Inserting raw bytes into a string

Tags: python, string, binary, serial-port

If I have a variable, number = 255

How do I go about inserting its binary value into a string exactly as it is in memory, not converting it into an ascii representation, as in 3 characters.

string = "my number is " + number "!"

So in this case in memory would be the string as it is normally as ascii but where the variable is it would be just one byte and be 11111111. Again thats not 11111111 in ascii (as in not 8 chars).

The purpose of this is that i've been sending data through serial to my microcontroller but so far its all been in ascii, any numbers I send are converted to ascii, so 255 would be 3 bytes, but im trying to make everything a bit more efficient by sending any number as their raw binary value. (At the moment no number that I need to send will be bigger than 255 so can be done in one byte)

I understand that I will need to decide on an escape character if I go down this route so I don't accidentally represent a command symbol with my raw binary data but that isn't an issue.

EDIT: Just mentioning that I know I have to encode my strings as ascii as python is unicode by default. If anyone was to mention that

Comment: In Python 3, you're looking for `bytes()`, or the byte literal representation: `b'...'`. To do 255 in binary you could do `bytes([255])`, or `b'\xff'` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `chr` function, at least for Python 2.7:

```
>>> print "Byte 65:" + chr(65)
Byte 65:A
```

('A' being the "textual representation" of the "single byte" 65 ...)

*Note:*
As you've mentioned, strings in Python 3.0 are represented in unicode, i.e. in a multibyte format. You will get an error if you try to encode values > 128 using the ascii codec.

So for sending raw data through a serial interface you should probably use `bytes`, if your serial library supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [struct.pack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Probably something like:

```
string = "my number is " + struct.pack('B',number)
```

Comment: Theoretically, `struct.pack` might add padding/alignment bytes, depending on the C compiler used to compile python. I think that `struct.pack('=B',number)` will give a standardized packing with no padding.